# Is String.prototype.replace() buggy?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, prototype

Consider the following snippet,

```js
console.log('A B'.replace('A', "$'"))
```

I expected the output to be: `$' B`

But the actual output:  `B B`

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: _"Can someone explain this behavior?"_ - Any documentation for that function, or the specification itself: [22.1.3.17 `String.prototype.replace`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.replace) -> 12.c -> [22.1.3.17.1 GetSubstitution](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getsubstitution) -> 10.

Answer (score 1):

The `$` indicates a [placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in the replacement string:

| Pattern | Inserts |
| --- | --- |
| `$$` | Inserts a "$". |
| `$&` | Inserts the matched substring. |
| `` $` `` | Inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring. |
| `$'` | Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring. |
| `$n` | Where *n* is a positive integer less than 100, inserts the *n*th parenthesized submatch string, provided the first argument was a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object. Note that this is 1-indexed. If a group `n` is not present (e.g., if group is 3), it will be replaced as a literal (e.g., $3). |
| `$<Name>` | Where `Name` is a capturing group name. If the group is not in the match, or not in the regular expression, or if a string was passed as the first argument to `replace` instead of a regular expression, this resolves to a literal (e.g., `$<Name>`). Only available in browser versions supporting named capturing groups. |

Comment: Why don't you close it as a dupe?

Answer (score 0):

According to the MDN docs and as referenced in the comments:

$'  Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.